# In monotouch how to convert string to decimal/float?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I am converting `string` to `Float`/`Decimal` in `monotouch` but it is giving format exception. I am using `Decimal.Parse()`, `Convert.ToDecimal()`. Please give any solution for this conversion.

```cs
decimal d = Convert.ToDecimal(UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SystemVersion, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); 

decimal d = Decimal.Parse(UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SystemVersion, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: What does SystemVersion return? If it returns something like "7.0.2", it cannot be converted to a number.

Comment: Yes,it is returning "7.0.2".So,what's the solution to convert it to decimal?

Comment: Use Decimal.ParseExact() and provide a Format string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SystemVersion` is a string with multiple dots `.` characters. That won't parse correctly *as is* into a float or a decimal.

Depending on what you want you could modify the string before parsing. E.g. if you want `7.0` out of the string `7.0.2` then you could so a substring (up to the 2nd `.` character).

OTOH if what you need to do is a version check (most common operation) then you only need to do this:

```
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion (7,0)) {
   // do this in iOS7+
} else {
   // do this before iOS7
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`System.Version`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.aspx) has a [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version.aspx) that parses that kind of `string`, from 2 to 4 components, in the form of:

```
major.minor[.build[.revision]]
```

So, to parse `UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SystemVersion` you can do:

```cs
var version = new Version (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.SystemVersion);

if (version.Major >= 7) {
    //iOS7+
} else {
    // anything else
}
```

If you're trying to figure out a particular version, use this. Otherwise @poupou's solution is great and more iOS-minded.